# Jade атрибуты на русском

Tags: gulp, jade

```
a(href="#link" data-text="Текст")
```

Компилируется в

```
<a href="#link" data-text="&#x422;&#x435;&#x43A;&#x441;&#x442;"></a>
```

Как этого избежать и сохранить исходный текст атрибута?
Использую gulp как сборщик и gulp-beml для BEML шаблонизации.

**Из комментария:**
Используется [gulp-jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade), [gulp-jade-inheritance](https://github.com/juanfran/gulp-jade-inheritance), [gulp-beml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-beml)

Comment: Какой пакет используется для компиляции jade?

Comment: В общем случае, я посоветую вам для начала выявить, какой из пакетов преобразует кириллицу в utf8-последовательность и посмотреть существующие Issue для этого пакета, если таковые есть, на наличие схожей проблемы и ее возможного решения.

Comment: Используется [gulp-jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade), [gulp-jade-inheritance](https://github.com/juanfran/gulp-jade-inheritance), [gulp-beml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-beml)

Comment: Сам использую gulp-jade, такой проблемы не наблюдаю. Попробуйте временно отключить gulp-beml плагин и проверьте наличие проблемы.

Comment: Да, вы правы, без gulp-beml такой проблемы не наблюдается. Надо  мне думать что можно сделать с этим плагином и его кодировкой, очень уж привык.

Comment: Быстрее будет написать разработчику на GitHub. По-моему, он русский.

Comment: Написал разработчику и дал ссылку на вопрос. Буду ждать обратной связи.

Answer (score 1):

Была установлена ранняя версия gulp-beml. Обновление решает проблему.